# filter query by count

Tags: sql

table structure (id,create-date,mobileno)

Sample data

```
(1,2018-01-01,9999999999)
(2,2018-01-01,9999999999)
(3,2018-01-01,9999999999)
(4,2018-01-02,8888888888)
(5,2018-01-03,7777777777)
(6,2018-01-03,7777777777)
```

DESIRED OUTPUT SHOULD LIST

1. Mobile number  HAVING MOBILE NUMBER COUNT GREATER THAN 2
   (RESULT should be 9999999999).

Comment: What query have you tried writing yet ? SO is not a free code writing service. You should post your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want a basic group by query:

```
SELECT mobileno, COUNT(*) AS num_occurrences
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY mobileno
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
```

Comment: THANKS also need number of occurrence of mobilenno